# Git branch behind master despite being identical

Tags: git, github

I have a setup with a local dev, remote dev and a remote master branch.
When Im done working locally I push everything onto the origin/dev and then merge it into the origin/master.

So I did a pull request and merged the origin/dev into the master and everything seemed fine. But when I check on github it says that the origin/dev is three commits behind the master, even though the two branches are identical when I compare them.
I have never done any commits from the master branch.

Is this normal?

Comment: Create a PR `origin/master > origin/dev` to find out exactly which commits are known only to `master` and not to `dev` (then delete the PR when you're done). My guess is they're the merge commits done on `master`. Nothing to worry about in this case.

Comment: These are all meaningless descriptions. Please show the actual commands you gave to git, and what git replied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inspect the branches on your local machine :

- run `git fetch` to have an up to date view of the remote repo (this will update `origin/master` and `origin/dev`),
- you can use a graphical viewer (inspect the history of `origin/master`), or run `git log` in a terminal to view what commits are part of `origin/master` and `origin/dev` :

  ```
  git log --oneline --graph origin/master origin/dev
  ```

---

I agree with @RomainValeri : my guess is you will see something like :

```
* ee1234 (origin/master)   # <- merge commit corresponding to the merge request
|\
| * adcc41 (origin/dev)   # <- dev hasn't moved yet
| * bdaa67
| * edaa12
| ...
* dd1234    # <- probably two extra commits, which are on master but not on dev
* cc1234
|/
* ff3112    # <- the forking point between master and dev
            #    or the last merge of master into dev
```

In the diagram above, the 3 commits `cc1234`, `dd1234` and `ee1234` are part of `origin/master` and not part of `origin/dev`, so `dev` is announced as "3 commits behind" `master`.

---

"Fixing" obviously depends on what you want to do, a plausible next step is :

- merge `master` into `dev`